# How to make a reminder in mysql with date stored in unix_timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Please I am making a reminder to start sending mails for events starting in 7 days or less.
That is send mails to attendees to events starting in 0 - 7 days only.

Where I need help is on this line:

```
...WHERE event_start_date > '$current_time' //currently sends to all attendees for all events starting in future

$current_time = time();
```

How can I change that to reflect what I need?
Kindly note date is stored in unix_timestamp.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Get the current unix timestamp.

```
$current_time = time();
```

As it is stored in seconds, you can add to it by adding 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 7 days to get the unix timestamp in a week.

```
$weekFromNow=$current_time+(60*60*24*7);
```

Now just find events where the `event_start_date` is less than or equal to it.

```
...WHERE event_start_date <= '$weekFromNow' 
         and event_start_date > '$current_time'
//sends to all attendees for all events starting in future
```

Edit: as `$weekFromNow` is one week into the future, the query needs to find all times less than or equal to that value, which is what the query does. If your `event_start_date` holds some value OTHER than the unix timestamp of the event starting time, let me know.

Comment: This is wrong as it will show events starting in more than 7 days.

Comment: Okay, I assumed that event_start_date was the unix timestamp of the event starting time? Also, I edited my answer about a minute after I posted it. Did you grab it right off the bat?

Comment: Your query will show events started yesterday and so on which is not the expected result. Rather to show events starting in 7 days or less and not yesterday. Remember yesterday is less than 7 days according to your query. say yesterday is 123445558 in unix timestamp and a week from now will always be more than yesterday.

Comment: I am currently playing around something like - ...WHERE (event_start_date <= '$weekFromNow' AND event_start_date > '$current_time') //will update this thread on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this in MySQL only, without determining the time in PHP first. I don't think it's faster, but it's a lot more readable.:

```
...WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(event_start_date) <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

However, this also returns events starting before today. If you don't want that, you could use:

```
...WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(event_start_date) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

(adapted from [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html))

Comment: Will try the second query and update the thread. Thanks all for your support.